# Flask AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: index

Tags: python, flask

My first hello world program is not working.

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "<h1>Hello world</h1>"

if __name__=='__main__':
        app.run()
```

And this is my output:

```
(myflaskenv) C:\Users\saini computers\Desktop\flask_examples>python 
 basic.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic.py", line 6, in <module>
    @app.route('/information')
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myflaskenv\lib\site- 
  packages\flask\app.py", line 1250, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myflaskenv\lib\site- 
  packages\flask\app.py", line 66, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\saini computers\Anaconda3\envs\myflaskenv\lib\site- 
  packages\flask\app.py", line 1221, in add_url_rule
    'existing endpoint function: %s' % endpoint)
```

> AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint
> function: index

Comment: is this your complete code? the error log shows @app.route('/information'), but I cannot see that in your code?

Comment: This should work. Are you sure that you do not have any unsaved changes and that you are running this code from correct directory?

Comment: Thank you!!! The code was actually unsaved.I saved it again and it is working now :)

Answer (score 8):

> AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: index

This error indicates that you have used same method name in multiple routes.

You can reproduce the error using the following code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "hello from index"

@app.route("/info")
def index():
    return "hello from info"

app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

Error trace:

```
(venv) ➜ python app.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 9, in <module>
    @app.route("/info", methods=['GET'])
  File ".../app.py", line 1250, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File ".../app.py", line 66, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".../app.py", line 1221, in add_url_rule
    'existing endpoint function: %s' % endpoint)
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: index
```

Both routes `@app.route("/info")` and `@app.route("/")` use same method called `index`. So I am getting the error: `AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: index`

I think, you are making same mistake. You are using method `index` for both `/` and `/information` route.

Answer (score 4):

As of version 4.x.x, it is now @jwt_required() instead of jwt_required. If you are updating an existing application, you can find a link to all of the breaking changes in the 4.x.x release on the README.

Answer (score 1):

When writing decorators for Flask, you need to decorate the inner wrapper with `wraps(func)` as described in the [official documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/viewdecorators/):

> A decorator is a function that wraps and replaces another function. Since the original function is replaced, you need to remember to copy the original function’s information to the new function. Use [functools.wraps()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to handle this for you.

Comment: This was it - I'm writing custom decorators that accept params. You need to decorate the inner wrapper for flask to boot properly

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was because I was initiating the flask app wrongly. In the main app file I was using the factory pattern but in the end of the file I was creating a app variable like:

```
app = create_app()
```

removing that part solves for me